# Product between an exponential function and an exponential matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, stochastic-processes, laplace-transform

I am writing a dissertation on continuous time Markov's chains and I need some help to calculate the resolvent $R(\lambda)$ of the transition rate function $Q$ of a process. The resolvent is defined as the Laplace transform of the transition probability matrix $P(t)$, which is a matrix-function of time that is proved to be equal to the exponential matrix function $e^{Qt}$ using the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation.

The first doubt that I have is the following: How can I be sure that the Laplace transform of $e^{Qt}$ is defined?

Assuming that it is well defined, by applying the definition we get that the resolvent $R$ is equal to the following integral
$$R(\lambda)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\lambda t}e^{Qt}dt.$$
The ideal solution that I am expecting here is the following
$$R(\lambda)=(\lambda I-Q)^{-1},$$
but to get to thet results I should be able to show that $e^{-\lambda t}$ $e^{Qt}=e^{-(\lambda I-Q)t}$. I tried to use the definition of the exponential of a matrix to get to that expression but it led to nothing. I also tried to use Cauchy's series product but I am not sure that it can be applied between seried that have different "dimension".

Comment: For the "problem of dimension", maybe you can use the fact that $e^\alpha M = e^\alpha I M = e^{\alpha I} M$?

Comment: Ok that should solve the problem I had about the Resolvent definition. The identity Matrix Is such that MI=IM so I can get to $e^{-(\lambda I-Q)t}$.